# jgraphx overline vertex labels

Tags: java, html, jgraphx

i'm trying to overline vertex labels via HTML-Code in java, but it doesn't work.
underline and line-through work perfectly, but i really need overline

```
cell.setValue("<span style=\"text-decoration:overline\">hiii</span>");
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Java supports a limited subset of CSS functions when rendering HTML, the list is in the [JavaDocs of the CSS class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html).

As you can see in the supported list

> text-decoration (with the exception of blink and overline)

There's not much can be done until Java supports the functionality.